# Read from JSON Array into Grails HTML Select tag

Tags: html, json, grails

I am using the [Grails select](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html) tag on my gsp. When I call the backend to populate this guy, the values comes in as a JSON array like so..

```
[{"id":1,"display_name":"Sarah's Site"},
 {"id":2,"display_name":"Gisele's Site"},
 {"id":3,"display_name":"Mariam's Site"}
 ]
```

So I basically want to feed the id list into the keys attribute of the tag and the display_name list into the from attribute. So that the user sees a list of the display names and when they select one then the id is passed backed to the controller.

Not sure how exactly to do this, here is the code I am staring at now...

```
<g:select id="siteId" name="siteId" from="${siteNameList}" keys="${siteNameList}" noSelection="['':'Any']"/>
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I extracted two lists from the JSON Array (results) and passed it to the GSP view like so..

```
    def keys = [];
    def values = []

    results.each {
      keys.add(it.get("id"))
        values.add(it.get("display_name"))
    }
 render(view: "main", model:[siteNameKeys:keys, siteNameValues:values])
```

And then I just passed these lists to the from and keys attribute of the select tag.

```
<g:select id="siteId" name="siteId" from="${siteNameValues}" keys="${siteNameKeys}"
```